# How can I skip caching when using save() method of CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, database, postgresql

I have two separate applications that using the same DB.

When the first one saves entity by `CrudRepository.save()` it sends notification to the second application and it's invalidates custom cache.
The problem is: when the first application saves entity it stands in the first level cache and the second application gets unchanged value.

How can I skip this caching or force to flush entity to the database?

Comment: You could try to manually force the flush if you can get access to the entity manager or just send the notification at the end of the transaction (1st level cache is bound to the session life time which normally is bound to the transaction, so the flush should happen at the end of the transaction at the latest).

Comment: @Thomas as I see it: transaction ends after save() method returned value (generated id, saved, cached, returned) and right after that I could expect that new value saved to the database and not the cache, am I wrong?

Comment: When the transaction ends depends on how you set up your application. By default the repository should join any already existing transaction so if your code already opened one it should still be open after the call to `save()`. It also depends on whether you have changed session life time, i.e. whether closing the transaction also closes the Hibernate session. If that's the case then closing the session should cause the flush - unless you set it to manual flushing anyway. Does your entity get flushed eventually?

Comment: @Thomas yes it flushed some time ago. But I got your point. Thanks for replies, I will continue investigations.

Comment: `flush` isn't a commit, even if you flush and your transaction hasn't committed you cannot see the data. YOur data will only be visible **after** the transaction has ended, which is generally **after** the service method that executes has finished. So no not after the call to `save` on the repository.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your reply! I've found `TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization()` where I can register some logic that should be executed after commit by overriding `afterCommit()` method in anonymous class. Seems like it could solve my issue.

Comment: If you are on a recent version you can use a transactional eventlistener to execute code after transaction commit. This is more flexible and easier to use.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, I chose the eventlistener as an approach in this case, many thanks!